# elasticsearch update operation on not-indexed fields

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

If I update a field in my document that is mapped as NOT indexed, will ES still re-index the whole document? If so is it because _source need to be re-indexed? Is it possible not to index _source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_source` is not indexed by default](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html), just stored. And yes, ES will re-index the document because this is the only way in which a document can be updated: a new one is created, the old one is deleted.

This is a basic principle in ES: Lucene segments (files on disk) are [immutable and cannot be changed](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/dynamic-indices.html#deletes-and-updates), only deleted (through merging) or added.